# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I create  python Project and make a class with some methods and property (variable) when I run my script the Python Interpretation tell me:

Traceback (most recent call last):
child.class@gmail.com

File "C:/.../Python_Tutorials/Object_Orinted_Programming.py", line 272, in 
    Child_Instance.name("child")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

it is the Code:

```
class Mother_Class:
    def __init__(self,parm1,parm2):
        self.name = (parm1)
        self.family = (parm2)
        self.full_name = (self.name + " " + self.family)
        self.email = (self.name+"."+self.family+"@gmail.com")
    def full_name(self,parm1,parm2):
        print ("Your Full Name is: "+parm1 + "" + parm2)



class Child_Class(Mother_Class):

    def name(self,name):
        name = ( name )

    def family(self,family):
        family = ( family )

    def Some_Methods(self):
        print ("Some information is Here: ")


Instance = Mother_Class("mother","class")
print (Instance.full_name)
print (Instance.email)

print ("")

Child_Instance = Child_Class("child","class")
Child_Instance.name("overwriteclass")
print (Child_Instance.full_name)
```

What are the Problems?

Comment: A few things. 1) Don't name both a function and a variable `name`. One definition overwrites the other because they're all in the same namespace. 2) Setting `name = (name)` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: thanks a lot for your great help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method rewrites the method `name` with the value passed to the function.

```
def name(self,name):
    name = ( name )
```

So, when you then try to call the "method", you're actually trying to call the string that you overwrote the method with.

Fixing is going to require a structural change of some sort because you are trying  to use `name` as both a method name and a property name. Maybe:

```
def set_name(self, name):
    self.name = name
```